# purpose of static and void for one of Collections methods

Tags: java, collections

What is the purpose of  static and void in this context
:

```
public static <T> void sort (List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c){}
```

Comment: Please go through java api documentation and little research before giving up and asking

Answer (score 4):

This is a method that can be called on any list, passed as an argument. No return value is required. It's provided by the Collections class, which consists entirely of static methods.

`static`: The method can be called without requiring an instance of the Collections class on which it is called.

`void`: The method does not return anything.

Comment: He's obviously not asking the question he wants answered lol.

Answer (score 0):

These are absolutely different things.

`void` method is a method that does not return anything. Other languages (like good old Fortran or Pascal) have different keywords for such type of modules. In Fortran module that does not return anything is called `subroutine` while one that returns values is called `function`. In Pascal they are called `procedure` and `function`.

In C programming languages and other languages that inherited its syntax there is no different keywords, however "dummy" return type `void` was introduced.

`static` method means method that belongs to whole class. You can call it by specifying class name without a need to create object (instance) of the class.  Static methods are useful for implementing utilities (e.g. `Math` class of JDK).